# HP Proliant ML350 G5 Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, hp, hp-proliant, operating-system

We have two types of servers we need to upgrade to Windows Server 2012 64bit

- HP Proliant DL380 G6
- HP Proliant ML350 G5

I think they both have licenses for Windows Server 2008 but they are currently running Windows Server 2003.

I have seen on their website that Windows Server 2012 should work on the DL380 server but I am not sure about the ML 350.

http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/windows.aspx#.WWbHglElGUk

Can I install and run Windows Server 2012 on my HP Proliant ML350 G5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Windows 2012 will run on your G5 ProLiant.

However, G5 servers date back to 2005. So installing a atop such an old platform may not be the best idea.